# Flutter showDialog without context in DataSourceTable's outline button

Tags: flutter

I am making a web app for publishing on the internet with Flutter. I have tried to show only a dialog for my customers in DataSourceTable. But My code is not working.

I tried the Getx methods and created the navigator key methods. But it is not working.

I only did create a custom widget dialog. And I put it on my outlinebutton. But Unfortunately, I can not access to context material in DataTableSource.

You can look up to my code in below:

My custom widget dialog:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class simple_box_confirm_general extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final String button_text;
  final VoidCallback onPress;


  const simple_box_confirm_general({super.key, required this.text, required this.button_text, required this.onPress });

  @override
  State<simple_box_confirm_general> createState() => _simple_box_confirm_generalState();
}

class _simple_box_confirm_generalState extends State<simple_box_confirm_general> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
      ),
      child: Container(
        height: 350,
        width: 100,
        child: Column(

            children: [
              SizedBox(height: height/20,),
              Positioned(
                  right: 0,
                  top: -60,

                  child: Image.asset("images/confirm.png")),
              SizedBox(height: height/20,),

              Text("${widget.text}", style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.black) , ),

              SizedBox(height: height/20,),

              Container(
                height: height/20,
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
                child: OutlinedButton(

                  onPressed: () => widget.onPress(),










                      //    MyApp.crossfade = false;











                    //   print(MyApp.crossfade);





                  style: ButtonStyle(

                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green[800]),
                    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0) , )),
                  ),
                  child:  Text("${widget.button_text}" , style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,),),
                ),


              )




            ]),


      ),


    );
  }
}
```

And my DataTableSource :

```
class MyKasaData extends DataTableSource {


  SideBarController sideBarController = Get.put(SideBarController());


  // List<Kasalar> kasalar = [];

  //MyKasaData(this._data);
 MyKasaData(this._data);

  final List<dynamic> _data;






  FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;


  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow(cells: [
    DataCell(Text(_data[index].data()['kasa_adi'])),

    DataCell(Text(_data[index].data()['acilis_bakiyesi'])),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].data()['doviz_cinsi'])),
    DataCell(Text(_data[index].data()['olusturulma_tarihi'])),
    DataCell(Text(_data[index].data()['aktivite'])),

/*      DataCell(Text(_data[index].kasa_adi)),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].doviz_cinsi)),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].acilis_bakiyesi)),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].olusturulma_tarihi)),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].aktivite)),*/
      DataCell(

          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
                height: 50,
                child: Row(
                  children: [

                    Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 50,
                      child: OutlinedButton(
                        key: GlobalKey(),
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0) , )),
                            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),


                          ),


                          onPressed: () {
                            print("hello worlds");
                     
               //             sideBarController.showdialog();

// context is not accessible.
                          showDialog(context:  navigatorKey.currentState!.overlay!.context, builder: (BuildContext context) {

                              return  simple_box_confirm_general(text: "E-mail sıfırlama postası gönderildi.", button_text: "Şifreniz sıfırlandı.", onPress: () {

                                Navigator.pop(context);

                              }

                              );

                            });






                            /*       showDialog(
                                context: Get.context,
                                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                  return AlertDialog(
                                    title: Text("title"),
                                    content: Text("message"),

                                  );
                                });
                            Get.dialog(SimpleDialog(children: [
                              Container(
                                width: 200,
                                height: 300,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),


                            ],));
*/
                         //   sideBarController.showdialog();




                    //    print(_data[index].reference.id);
                      //      print(_data[index].reference.id);


                    //  _firestore.collection("Users").doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email).collection("kasalar").doc(_data[index].reference.id).delete();

                      /*     showDialog(context:   , builder: (BuildContext context) {

                              return  simpleCustom_confirm(text: "E-mail sıfırlama postası gönderildi.", button_text: "Şifreniz sıfırlandı.",);
// hatayberkay1234@gmail.com
                            });*/


                          }, child: Text("Sil", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10 ,  fontFamily: 'Poppins', color: Colors.black),) ),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(width: 5,),

                    Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 50,
                      child: OutlinedButton(
                          key: GlobalKey(),
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0) , )),
                            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.yellow),


                          ),


                          onPressed: () {

                     // document'in idsini verir.




                         sideBarController.kasa_duzenle_id.value =  _data[index].reference.id;


                            //  sideBarController.kasa_duzenle_id.value = _data[index]["id"].toString();

                            sideBarController.index.value = 22;
                            selected: sideBarController.index.value == 22;




                          }, child: Text("Düzenle" , style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10  ,  fontFamily: 'Poppins', color: Colors.black ),)),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 5,),

                    Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 50,
                      child: OutlinedButton(
                          key: GlobalKey(),
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0) , )),
                            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),


                          ),


                          onPressed: () {


                            sideBarController.kasa_duzenle_id.value =  _data[index].reference.id;
                            sideBarController.index.value = 23;
                            selected: sideBarController.index.value == 23;



                          }, child: Text("Hareket İzle" , style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10 ,  fontFamily: 'Poppins',color: Colors.black),)),
                    ),


                  ],



                )),
          )),
```

I just want to show it when I pressed to button my custom widget dialog. How can I do it?